# Irreducible representations of $\mathrm{UHF}_n$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I have a question about the irreducible representations of the $C^*$-algebra $\mathrm{UHF}_n = \bigotimes_{k=1}^\infty M_n$.

For every sequence of unit vectors $(\xi_k)$ in $\mathbb C^n$ there is a natural representation of $\mathrm{UHF}_n$ on the infinite Hilbert space tensor product $H = \bigotimes_{k=1}^\infty (\mathbb C^n,\xi_k)$.
This representation is always irreducible.
My question is:

*Are all irreducible representations of $\mathrm{UHF}_n$ of this form?*

---

Some comments/thoughts:

- Since such a representation is the GNS representation of the pure product state $\omega =\otimes_k \omega_k$ with $\omega_k(a)=\langle a\xi_k,\xi_k\rangle$, the question is equivalent to: *Are all pure states on $\mathrm{UHF}_n$ contained in the folium of a pure product state?*
- An irreducible representation of $\mathrm{UHF}_n$ on a Hilbert space $H$ corresponds to an increasing sequence $R_k$, $k\in\mathbb N$, of type $\text I_{n^k}$ factors which generate $B(H)$, i.e., $(\bigcup_k R_k)''=B(H)$.
  For each finite $N$, this induces a tensor product decomposition $H\cong (\mathbb C^n)^{\otimes N} \otimes K_N$ (with $K_N = p_N H$ where $p_N$ is a minimal projection in $R_N$). Even though this holds for all $N\in\mathbb N$, I dont see that it implies that $H$ is an infinite tensor product.
- By uniqueness of the GNS representation an affirmative answer is equivalent to: For each increasing sequence $R_k$, $k\in\mathbb N$, of type $\text I_{n^k}$ factors on a separable Hilbert space $H$ which generates $B(H)$ there exists a vector $0\ne \xi\in H$ that is a product vector with respect to each of the induced tensor product decompositions $H\cong (\mathbb C^n)^{\otimes N}\otimes K_N$.
- Another aspect that could be related is the natural action of $\mathrm{UHF}_n$ on the non-separable infinite Hilbert space tensor product $\tilde\bigotimes_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb C^n$ (as defined by von Neumann). Is this (quasi-equivalent to) the universal representation?
- Of course these question makes sense for all UHF algebras.

Comment: Perhaps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220148/powers-theorem-for-irreducible-representations?rq=1 gets you closer to what you want.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey Hi Chris. Thanks for pointing that out! I still need to wrap my head around the representations that Gårding and Wightman construct. In the last sentence of their paper, they indicate that they do not know if all irreps are of the constructed form. It seems that we don't know all irreps of $\mathrm{UHF}_2=\mathrm{CAR}$.